# How can I use a calculated value of a function in another function in another Python file?

Tags: python, variables

I have wrote the following code in `derivation.py`:

```
def Interpolation(ableitungWinkel,x_values):
    
    z = medfilt(derivation,3)
    diff = abs(derivation-z) 
    new_smootheddata = np.where(diff>3,z,derivation)
    x=np.arange(0,len(x_values[:-2]))    
    f = interp1d(x,new_smootheddata,kind="linear")   
    xnew = np.arange(0, len(x_values[:-3]),0.01)
    ynew = f(xnew)
    s=plt.plot(x, z,"o",xnew, ynew, "-")
    
    return s
```

In my project there is also `integration.py`. In this Python file I need the values which *z* calculates in the function `def interpolation` for this calculation:

```
def horizontalAcceleration(strideData):
    resultsHorizontal = list()

    for i in range (len(strideData)):
        yAngle = z
        xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
        yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
        
        a = ((m.cos(m.radians(yAngle)))*yAcceleration)-((m.sin(m.radians(yAngle)))*xAcceleration) 

        resultsHorizontal.append(a)

    resultsHorizontal.insert(0, 0)
    
    return resultsHorizontal
```

As you can see I have already added z to the function def horizontalAcceleration at the place where it should go.
To use z there, I tried the following: `from derivation import z`

But that doesn't work. Because then I get the error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'z' from 'derivation'**

Have anybody an idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You can only import functions from other files. You cannot import the results of the intermediate calculations from a function. You need your function horizontalAcceleration to accept an additional input z, which you should provide each time you call this function

Comment: Change your `Interpolation` function to return `s, z`, and then when you call that function, say `s, z = Interpolation(...)`.  Now you have access to both s and z values!

Comment: Did you mean: `yAngle = medfilt(derivation,3)`?

Comment: @quamrana yes. Thats z.

Comment: @Samwise you mean in `def Interpolation`I have to write return s, z

Comment: You could calculate: `z = medfilt(derivation,3)` before the `for` loop and still have your `yAngle = z` inside as it is now.

Comment: @quamrana I will try it

Comment: That doesn't work, because the function does not know what derivation is. So I have to hand it over

Comment: Perhaps you could write another function in `derivation.py`: `def get_z(): return medfilt(derivation,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your misunderstanding is because you think a function is like a script that has been run and modified a.global state. That's not what a function is. A function is a series of actions performed on its inputs (ignoring closures for a minute) which returns some results. You can call it many times, but without calling it, it never executes. Once it stops executing all its variables go out of scope.

You can import and call a function though. So you can change the return type of Interpolation to return everything you need somewhere else. E.g.

```
def Interpolation(...):
...
return {'z': z, 's': s}
```

Then somewhere you import that function, call it, get back all the data you need, then pass that to your other function.

```
import Interpolation from derivation
# get z and s in a dict result
result = Interpolation(...)
# pass s as well as the other argument to your other function
horizontalAcceleration(strideData, result['s'])
```

Comment: Thank you! :) It helps a lot